# Most simple sound format?

Tags: audio

I was reading about bitmap images.  They are one of the more simple image formats (especially 1 bit bitmaps).  I am interested to see what a sound file looks like.  May someone refer me to the most simple sound file format?

thanks

Actually, I found this [wav file link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113025807/http://technology.niagarac.on.ca:80/courses/ctec1631/WavFileFormat.html).  If someone else has any other links/words of wisdom they'd like to post I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 10):

8-bit mono uncompressed WAV, in my opinion...

[wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)

Comment: technically yes that is the "simplest", but its well worth going 16 bit if you want half-decent sound quality.

Answer (score 5):

Wave files are the simplest sound format.  They have a header (which can sometimes be complicated but usually isn't), and then the actual sound data is raw, uncompressed PCM.  Because they're uncompressed, though, they get very big very fast for even moderately long sounds.

Comment: err... in reference to the header and larger byte size

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, WAV files are not the simplest and contain a header.

1 bit PWM (pulse width modulated) audio could be considered the simplest in the relative terms to a 1 bit encoded bitmap image.

The principal is the same albeit in two dimensions for the bitmap as opposed to the single dimension for the audio.

[More about pulse width modulation in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)

Gift cards with sound and any cheap toy that plays back sound use PWM audio encoding techniques usually with a piezo as the transducer (speaker).

Comment: Byte-per-sample linear would arguably be simpler (somewhat analogous to 8-bit grayscale), since there are only two plausible formats (signed and unsigned).  With bit-per-sample, there are more formats.  Not only could data be sent with each byte LSbit first or MSbit first, but one might e.g. have 32-bit words that are sent MSbit first but stored LSbyte first, or have audio stored as bit 0 of every byte, followed by bit 1 of every byte, bit 2, etc. [a form I've encountered in 8088 or 6502 code that played sounds through a PC or Apple II speaker].

Answer (score 1):

Similar to repressing one bit image you can represent audio with one bit, only issue is you will not be able to hear anything from it.  Since to hear sounds wave of pressure changes needs to be generated from a device (headphone/speakers) it does not correspond well.  This is fundamentally due to audio being continues media and graphics being a still media.

You can represent audio with lower than 8 bits per sample and fewer samples per second.  Where you will represent it with lower resolution and loose higher frequencies respectively.  For an example- if you use 8 bits to represent each sample, limitation of 50 dB of SNR (signal to noise). By placing 8000 samples per second its possible to represent up to 4 kHz of bandwidth (old time telephony audio quality).

On the other hand if you represent each sample with 16 bit and 44,100 samples per second, we get CD quality audio.
In the raw form lowers number of bits and samples depend on the expectations of the user, similar to how low resolutions of image is acceptable to a user

Audio compression is used to reduce the bits used in samples as well as amount of samples.  They are based on compression techniques like ZIP files as well as CELP ( code excited linear prediction) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-excited_linear_prediction
 mp3, AMR-nb are algorithms which uses there techniques

Comment: "only issue is you will not be able to hear anything from it." this simple not true, you should check reality before making such claims. Quality would be poor, that's for sure, but you will hear what is there.

Answer (score 0):

WAV is the way to go, although be wary - the WAV file format may actually store compressed data - though it usually doesn't.

I'm using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) recently to import raw sound data from a microcontroller system.  It can also export raw audio.

That way you can start with sound in nearly any format, and export it as a binary file according to your desire.  I'm using 16 bit signed, little endian, mono sound, for instance.  Very handy and very easy to manipulate in simple test programs.  Can probably even deserialize it in some programming languages into an array or vector.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Look into libsndfile
http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/

Answer (score 0):

In the case of compression ogg is the most compressed format

In the case of simplicity i think wav files are simplest

Answer (score 0):

There is another good explanation of baseline WAVE format:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
I used it to implement WAV reading/writing in C# from scratch without any problems.
P.S. `AudioFormat` is 1 for integer values and 3 for floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

Check the RAW audio format.

If it is 8 bits then it is the simplest to process.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_audio_format

Answer (score 0):

WAV files are fairly simple. They simply consist of multiple 8, 16, or 32-bit integers which indicate the "height" (the Y coordinate) of the wave at a given time. For example, a square wave may look like this in an 8-bit WAV:

```
00 FF 00 FF 00
```

This is, of course, drastically simplified.

Comment: That is not a WAV file. It is called 8-bit unsigned PCM.

Comment: @bsound Please note the last sentence, this answer is just a quick description of what makes up the bulk of a WAV file without actually delving into details of the format. That being said, for those who are interested in how to actually encode a wave file I found [this resource](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) helpful

Comment: That resource is partially right, it works with the condition that chunks are always ordered the same way as described. There are edge cases which would invalidate that information (eg. WAVE file generated by FFmpeg (a popular multimedia manipulation utiltity)) is different to the layout described.

Comment: @bsound Of course, it's the tyranny of the robustness principle :) Presumably, OP just wants a convenient format for encoding sound; if they wanted to write a stable application, there'd be no point in rolling their own audio format library